# C++ -- How to enforce VC6.0 create PDB file on release mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I need to know how to set up VC6.0 so that the builder will create PDB file even in release mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Project Settings, Link. Select the Category: "General" and check the "Generate Debug Info" box. After that, you can select the Category "Debug" and change settings about the debug file.

Here is the links to MSDN documentation about [PDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278542%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and [DEBUG information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235413%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: When in the release mode, I need to set the value of optimization as Maximization. In the same time, I need to generate the PDB file too. BTW, there is no such box called "Generate Debug Info"

Comment: Here is a [screenshot](http://mudge.net/cppclass/Configurations/images/20_vs_6_project_settings_exe_name.jpg) I've found, showing the "Generate Debug Info" checkbox. You can also change the project options (command line parameters), see my links.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is simply a setting in Project Settings to "Generate Debug Info". And there is another place where you specify the type of debug info to produce: map file, PDB (program database), et al.

Answer (score 1):

A very detailed explanation is found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260783%28v=vs.60%29.aspx